# How to remove border for active braces in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Sometimes I can't see where's a pointer because color of border the same like color of pointer.

[image: Braces]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This depends on how you have configured IntelliJ. In my setup it's here:

[image]

That's settings -> editor -> color scheme -> general : editor -> caret.

Comment: Thanks. But I still can't remove border around braces. I using material darker theme

Comment: No, but you can change the colour of the caret so that you can see it. You probably want to leave the border because it actually helps when the braces are far apart or unbalanced.

Comment: This will change the caret color not the matching braces, to remove the border from the braces you have to go settings -> editor -> color scheme -> general : code -> matched brace and then change the style from the effects dropdown from bordered to smth else, or just untick the effects checkbox for no special styling.

Comment: @ziz194 - You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I couldn't submit an answer for some reason. Maybe because yours is chosen as the correct answer?

Comment: That shouldn't stop you. It's blocked because it's closed now :)